# Trouble with boolean and if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

When I attempt this code:

```
public boolean eligibleForBonus(double salary) {
    if(salary >=40000) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }   

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (eligibleForBonus()){
    return (code I want to return);
    }
    else {
    return (code I want to return);
    }
    }
```

I get an  error on the (eligibleForBonus()) which says "The method eligibleForBonus(double) in the type Employee(the class) is not applicable for the arguments ()".
I am new to programming and I've tried everything I can think of but I can't get it right - any help would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Your method `eligibleForBonus` requires an argument and you're sending nothing when calling it.

Comment: Your `eligibleForBonus` method could simply be: `return salaray > 40000;`

Answer (score 5):

`eligibleForBonus()` needs a parameter of type `double` as you declared here

```
public boolean eligibleForBonus(double salary) {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helps :) However, no parameter I enter seems to work

Comment: @Nelly are you passing an `int`? You may been to put `.0` on the end for java to recognize it as a `double`. Or `(double)myInt`

Answer (score 0):

you have to give `eligibleForBonus` a **double** argument

e.g.

```
public String toString() {
    if (eligibleForBonus(100.0)){
    return (code I want to return);
    }
    else {
    return (code I want to return);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your method `eligibleForBonus(double salary)` expects an argument of type double  but in this
    `if (eligibleForBonus()){` you are just calling this method without any argument
    You need to pass an argument in this like `if (eligibleForBonus(1.2)){`

Answer (score 0):

Your method `eligibleForBonus` expects a parameter `(double salary)`. In your toString method, you are calling that method without passing any parameter: `if (eligibleForBonus())`. That's why its cribbing. Pass a valid parameter, e.g.:

```
if (eligibleForBonus (1000.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `eligibleForBonus(double salary)` checks, if a bonus is eligible on the basis of the salary. But when you call this method, you don't 'hand over' the salary, thus you get an exception. If the salary is for example 2000 use
 `if(elibibleForBonus(2000))`.